# How to get the Index from an Item in the QTreeView

Tags: c++, qt

My Qt-Application was built based on the `EditableTreeModel` example from Qt. In the `TreeModel` class there is a function called `getItem()` which takes the `QModelIndex` as a parameter and returns a `TreeItem`.

For my Application I need the reverse function: getting the `QModelIndex` from an `TreeItem`. This should be independent from the View. This means that I can't use the function `QTreeView::currentIndex()`.

Is there any good solution for my problem?

Comment: What is `TreeItem`?

Comment: @vahancho [`TreeItem`](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qtwidgets-itemviews-editabletreemodel-treeitem-h.html) from the Qt example

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need to call [`QAbstractItemModel::createIndex`](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qabstractitemmodel.html#createIndex) passing in the correct `row`, `column` and the item iteself.

**The following should work:**

```
QModelIndex TreeModel::indexForTreeItem(TreeItem* item)
{
    return createIndex(item->childNumber(), 0, item);
}
```

**An explanation of how I came to this:**

`createIndex` also takes a `void*` data pointer, which in the `EditableTreeModel` [`TreeModel`](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qtwidgets-itemviews-editabletreemodel-treemodel-cpp.html) example code, is a pointer to the `TreeItem`. You can see this is the case in the [`TreeModel::index`](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qtwidgets-itemviews-editabletreemodel-treemodel-cpp.html) member function:

```
QModelIndex TreeModel::index(int row, int column, const QModelIndex &parent) const
{
    if (parent.isValid() && parent.column() != 0)
        return QModelIndex();

    TreeItem *parentItem = getItem(parent);

    TreeItem *childItem = parentItem->child(row);
    if (childItem)
        return createIndex(row, column, childItem); // <-- here childItem is the TreeItem*
    else
        return QModelIndex();
}
```

Note that `QAbstractItemModel::createIndex` is a protected function, so you have to add a new member function to your `TreeModel` which creates the `QModelIndex` for you.

In order to calculate the **row** for a given `TreeItem` there is a member function `childNumber` which returns its index in its parent's list of children (ie: its row)

Unfortunately it is not possible to calculate the **column** for a given `TreeItem`, as a `TreeItem` contains all the data for its columns, so encompasses *all* columns. As such, a reasonable default would be to use `0` (the left-most column)

Comment: Thank you very much ! Your Solution was brilliant! I just added a Variable for the Column in the function and now it works perfectly!

Answer (score 0):

You can build a map from `TreeItem` to `QModelIndex` as following :

```
    void buildMap(const QModelIndex &index, const QAbstractItemModel *model, QMap<TreeItem *, QModelIndex> &itemMap)
    {
            if( !index.isValid() )
                    return;

            TreeItem *item = static_cast<TreeItem*>(index.internalPointer());
            itemMap.insert( item, index );

            int rows = model->rowCount(index);
            int cols = model->columnCount(index);

            for (int i = 0; i < rows; ++i)
                    for (int j = 0; j < cols; ++j){
                            QModelIndex idChild = model->index(i, j, index);
                            buildMap( idChild , model, itemMap );
                    }
    }
```

The function buildMap should be used as :

```
        QMap<TreeItem *, QModelIndex> itemMap;
        TreeModel *model = static_cast<TreeModel *>(view->model());

        for (int row = 0; row < model->rowCount(); ++row){
            buildMap( model->index(row,0), model, itemMap );
        }

        qDebug() << "Item map count : " << itemMap.count();

        foreach( TreeItem * item, itemMap.keys( )){
                qDebug() << "item " << item << " -> " << itemMap[ item ];
        }
```

Output:

```
    Item map count :  35
    item  0xbe1fe8  ->  QModelIndex(1,1,0xbe1fe8,TreeModel(0x4421390))
    item  0xbe2020  ->  QModelIndex(2,1,0xbe2020,TreeModel(0x4421390))
    item  0xbe22f8  ->  QModelIndex(3,1,0xbe22f8,TreeModel(0x4421390))
    item  0xbe2330  ->  QModelIndex(2,0,0xbe2330,TreeModel(0x4421390))
    ...
```