# How to create a QModelIndex to use with setCurrentItem from QtreeWidget?

Tags: c++, qt

Suppose I'm trying to set a `QTreeWidget` item at column 1 row 1 selected, how do I create a `QModelIndex` to use with `setCurrentItem`?

```
    QModelIndex index = ?
    setCurrentItem(itemFromIndex(index);
```

Or this is not the correct way to select a specific row item?

Comment: Retrieve model with `QTreeWidget::model()`. Then you can use `QAbstractItemModel::index()` to construct an index with a specific parent, row index, and column index. FYI: [How to get the Index from an Item in the QTreeView](https://stackoverflow.com/a/54148632/7478597)

Comment: @Scheff'sCat I'm subclassing the `QTreeWidget`, reading the link you sent, but I still didn't understand, what is `TreeModel` in her answer,  i tried `auto index = QTreeWidget::model();  index->index(0, 0); setCurrentItem(itemFromIndex(index);`

Comment: _but I still didn't understand, what is `TreeModel` in her answer_ In this case, it might be better to start with [Introduction to Model/View Programming](https://doc.qt.io/qt-6/model-view-programming.html)